Types of linear dependence
A set of $n$ vectors is linearly dependent if some vector can be expressed as a linear combination of the others. This is equivalent to saying that a linear combination of the $n$ vectors $a_1 a_2, \dots, a_n$ with coefficients $\lambda_i$, not all zero, exists such that.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i = 0.
$$
If we have a set of linearly dependent vectors such that a set of coefficients $\lambda_i$ all different from zero exists such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i a_i = 0.
$$
We have the stronger condition that all vectors can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.
The question is whether such a stronger linear dependence condition has a special name and whether such sets of linearly dependent vectors can be characterized in any additional interesting way.

As far as I know, this property does not have a name. On the one hand, one might at first thought think that the property implies that the collection of vectors is in some sense minimally independent, since every $a_i$ can be written as a linear combination where every $a_j$ for $i\neq j$ "contributes something". However, this is incorrect, since there could be additional dependencies among the other vectors. A concrete example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{4}\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
2
\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\end{bmatrix}^T$ can be written as a linear combination where all coefficients are non-zero, but it can also be written as two other linear combinations where some coefficients are zero, because of the other dependencies.
On the other hand, we do get something, justifying the statement that this is a stronger notion that linear dependence. Namely, every vector is spanned by some other vectors. This is not necessarily the case for regular linear dependence.

However, if you require that the coefficients are non-zero for all linear combinations, you do not encounter the above problem with extra dependencies. Then any vector is spanned by all other vectors, but any subset of $n-1$ vectors span $n-1$ dimensions, i.e., are linearly independent. In matroid language, such a set of vectors would be called a spanning circuit.
